# sending message with zmsg_send doesn't arrive after 3 times

Tags: zeromq

When using zmsg_send in a loop the first 2 messages arrives to the server and the 3rd does not. any solutions?

```
void main(void)
{
 // --------------------------------------------------------WAS MEANT SERIOUSLY:
    int            major,  minor,  patch;
    zmq_version ( &major, &minor, &patch );
    printf (                               "Current ØMQ version is %d.%d.%d\n",
                   major,  minor,  patch );
 // --------------------------------------------------------WAS MEANT SERIOUSLY

    zsock_t *client;
    zmsg_t *msg;

    client = zsock_new(ZMQ_REQ);
    zsock_connect(client, "ipc:///var/run/dummy_daemon.ipc");     
    while(true){
        msg = zmsg_new();
        zmsg_addstr(msg, "hello");
        zmsg_send(&msg, client);
        zmsg_recv(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to post a **C**omplete **M**C**VE**-code, as mandatory for StackOverflow ( may also re-read the Policy on this )? These three SLOCs are not **C**omplete and **cannot reproduce** the claim, the less **V**erify any solution approach. Best also include a call to **`zmq_version (&major, &minor, &patch);`** and **`printf ("Current ØMQ version is %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, patch);`**. That's fair, isn't it?

Comment: Added more details, thanks.

Comment: With all due respect, the MCVE-code is **still incomplete**, where is the **`REP`**-part?